# join files depending on filenames

Tags: perl, list, filenames

Example filenames:

```
example_12345_8943759847.csv
example_23456_9859877.csv
example_34567_92837458738.csv
example_12345_1165253.csv
example_23456_9983632652.csv
example_23456_2345.csv
```

I need to join files that have the same middle-number, eg. *23456*.csv
Thing is I don't know this middle-number so I suppose this has to be some variable?
I imagine I would have to list filenames with the same middle-part-number and then output this list?

I have only Perl or sed to my disposal.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "join files", I assume you mean concatenate files in the same way `cat file1 file2 ... > allfiles` would work?

Answer (score 2):

Here is part of the task (in Perl).  Finding groups of files that share the middle part:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = qw/
    example_12345_8943759847.csv
    example_23456_9859877.csv
    example_34567_92837458738.csv
    example_12345_1165253.csv
    example_23456_9983632652.csv
    example_23456_2345.csv
/;

my %middles;

#This creates a hash. The keys are the middle number; 
#the values are arrays of filenames that share that middle number.
foreach (@files)
{
    push @{$middles{$1}},$_ if (/[a-z]+_(\d+)_\d+\.csv/);
}

#Now process the results
foreach my $middle (keys %middles)
{
    #Get a group of filenames sharing the same middle part.
    my @files_to_join = @{$middles{$middle}};

    #Join them here...
}
```

The rest depends on what you mean by "joining".  You may find the [`Text::CSV` module](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) helpful for processing CSV files.